# Calling wx.frame class method for handling an events from a button on frame's panel

Tags: python, events, wxpython

I have the following class hierarchy:

wx.Frame derived class; within that frame I have a splitter window, and a wx.Panel based class linked to that splitter window. In the panel I have a button. I am binding an event handler to the button to do some actions. The problem is that most of the actions are supposed to be done within the frame class. So, somehow I have to call a method from the frame class in the button even handler. How can I do that? Relevant part of the code is below.

Cheers

```
class EPSPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        lbl_SGCR = wx.StaticText(self, label="SGCR", pos=(20, 20))
        self.ent_SGCR = wx.TextCtrl(self, value="", pos=(100,20), size=(200,-1))
        lbl_SWCR = wx.StaticText(self, label="SWCR", pos=(20, 60))
        self.ent_SWCR = wx.TextCtrl(self, value="", pos=(100,60), size=(200,-1))
        lbl_SWU = wx.StaticText(self, label="SWU", pos=(20, 100))
        self.ent_SWU = wx.TextCtrl(self, value="", pos=(100,100), size=(200,-1))
        lbl_SGU = wx.StaticText(self, label="SGU", pos=(20, 140))
        self.ent_SGU = wx.TextCtrl(self, value="", pos=(100,140), size=(200,-1))
        lbl_SWL = wx.StaticText(self, label="SWL", pos=(20, 180))
        self.ent_SWL = wx.TextCtrl(self, value="", pos=(100,180), size=(200,-1))
        lbl_SGL = wx.StaticText(self, label="SGL", pos=(20, 220))
        self.ent_SGL = wx.TextCtrl(self, value="", pos=(100,220), size=(200,-1))
        calc_button = wx.Button(self, label="Calculate", pos=(110,260))
        calc_button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.on_btn)

    def on_btn(self, event):
        self.set_SGCR = float(self.ent_SGCR.GetValue())
        self.set_SWCR = float(self.ent_SWCR.GetValue())
        self.set_SGU = float(self.ent_SGU.GetValue())
        self.set_SWU = float(self.ent_SWU.GetValue())
        # these four values in this method I need to pass to the KrFrame class
        # instance to process in one of its methods. I also need somehow
        # let the frame class know that that button was pressed. How can I do it?

class KrFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(parent=None,
             title='Gas Relative Permeability Editor', size=(900, 800))
        self.sp = wx.SplitterWindow(self)
        self.rightSplitter = wx.SplitterWindow(self.sp) #Another splitter to split right panel into two vertical ones
        self.leftSplitter = wx.SplitterWindow(self.sp)
        self.panel01 = KrPanel(self.leftSplitter)
        self.panel02 = PlotPanel(self.rightSplitter)
        self.panel03 = EPSPanel(self.rightSplitter) #Third panel for scaled end point entry
        self.panel04 = KrPanel(self.leftSplitter)
        self.rightSplitter.SplitHorizontally(self.panel02, self.panel03, 400) #Splitting right panel into two horizontally
        self.leftSplitter.SplitHorizontally(self.panel01, self.panel04, 400)
        self.sp.SplitVertically(self.leftSplitter, self.rightSplitter, 450)
        self.create_menu()
        self.Show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = KrFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
    del app
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Rolf. The issue is with sharing the code is that it already flourished over a number of modules and sharing all of them will result in several metres of scrolling. I found a workaround as below. My understanding  is that events are propagated among all parent classes from the child widget. Hence if the button is clicked, wxFrame gets the event too. So, I am doing the bind to an instance of the button class under the constructor of my WxFrame. In the binding I am defining event handling logic. This seems to work:

```
class KrFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(parent=None,
             title='Gas Relative Permeability Editor', size=(900, 800))
        self.sp = wx.SplitterWindow(self)
        self.rightSplitter = wx.SplitterWindow(self.sp) #Another splitter to split right panel into two vertical ones
        self.leftSplitter = wx.SplitterWindow(self.sp)
        self.panel01 = KrPanel(self.leftSplitter)
        self.panel02 = PlotPanel(self.rightSplitter)
        self.panel03 = EPSPanel(self.rightSplitter) #Third panel for scaled end point entry
```

## This is where I am binding an handler to the button click event

```
        self.panel03.calc_button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.on_btn)
        self.panel04 = KrPanel(self.leftSplitter)
        self.rightSplitter.SplitHorizontally(self.panel02, self.panel03, 400) #Splitting right panel into two horizontally
        self.leftSplitter.SplitHorizontally(self.panel01, self.panel04, 400)
        self.sp.SplitVertically(self.leftSplitter, self.rightSplitter, 450)
        self.create_menu()
        self.Show()

    def on_btn(self, event):
        self.set_SGCR = float(self.panel03.ent_SGCR.GetValue())
        self.set_SWCR = float(self.panel03.ent_SWCR.GetValue())
        self.set_SGU = float(self.panel03.ent_SGU.GetValue())
        self.set_SWU = float(self.panel03.ent_SWU.GetValue())
        print(self.set_SGCR, self.set_SWCR, self.set_SGU, self.set_SWU)
```

Comment: There are many ways to skin a cat, this method being one of the better ones :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can call a function defined within the frame, although to do something useful with the data, is made more difficult because you have defined a splitter window, within a splitter window, within a frame.
For future reference, it's best if you can provide a running version of sample code. Many people who could answer the question, do not want to have to re-hash the code to make it run.

This should give you food for thought.

```
import wx

class EPSPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)

        #track the real parent for updating purposes
        #
        self.parent = parent.GrandParent
        #
        lbl_SGCR = wx.StaticText(self, label="SGCR", pos=(20, 20))
        self.ent_SGCR = wx.TextCtrl(self, value="", pos=(100,20), size=(200,-1))
        lbl_SWCR = wx.StaticText(self, label="SWCR", pos=(20, 60))
        self.ent_SWCR = wx.TextCtrl(self, value="", pos=(100,60), size=(200,-1))
        lbl_SWU = wx.StaticText(self, label="SWU", pos=(20, 100))
        self.ent_SWU = wx.TextCtrl(self, value="", pos=(100,100), size=(200,-1))
        lbl_SGU = wx.StaticText(self, label="SGU", pos=(20, 140))
        self.ent_SGU = wx.TextCtrl(self, value="", pos=(100,140), size=(200,-1))
        lbl_SWL = wx.StaticText(self, label="SWL", pos=(20, 180))
        self.ent_SWL = wx.TextCtrl(self, value="", pos=(100,180), size=(200,-1))
        lbl_SGL = wx.StaticText(self, label="SGL", pos=(20, 220))
        self.ent_SGL = wx.TextCtrl(self, value="", pos=(100,220), size=(200,-1))
        calc_button = wx.Button(self, label="Calculate", pos=(110,260))
        calc_button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.on_btn)

    def on_btn(self, event):
        self.set_SGCR = float(self.ent_SGCR.GetValue())
        self.set_SWCR = float(self.ent_SWCR.GetValue())
        self.set_SGU = float(self.ent_SGU.GetValue())
        self.set_SWU = float(self.ent_SWU.GetValue())
        # these four values in this method I need to pass to the KrFrame class
        # instance to process in one of its methods. I also need somehow
        # let the frame class know that that button was pressed. How can I do it?

        KrFrame.mycalculation(self.parent,self.set_SGCR,self.set_SWCR,self.set_SGU,self.set_SWU)

class KrFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(parent=None,
             title='Gas Relative Permeability Editor', size=(900, 800))
        self.sp = wx.SplitterWindow(self)
        self.rightSplitter = wx.SplitterWindow(self.sp) #Another splitter to split right panel into two vertical ones
        self.leftSplitter = wx.SplitterWindow(self.sp)
        self.panel01 = wx.Panel(self.leftSplitter)

        self.Total = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel01)

        self.panel02 = wx.Panel(self.rightSplitter)
        self.panel03 = EPSPanel(self.rightSplitter) #Third panel for scaled end point entry
        self.panel04 = wx.Panel(self.leftSplitter)
        self.rightSplitter.SplitHorizontally(self.panel02, self.panel03, 400) #Splitting right panel into two horizontally
        self.leftSplitter.SplitHorizontally(self.panel01, self.panel04, 400)
        self.sp.SplitVertically(self.leftSplitter, self.rightSplitter, 450)
#        self.create_menu()
        self.Total.SetValue("00000.00")
        self.Show()

    def mycalculation(parent,SGCR=0,SWCR=0,SGU=0,SWU=0):
        print ("Total of values:",SGCR,SWCR,SGU,SWU,"=",SGCR+SWCR+SGU+SWU)
        parent.Total.SetValue(str(SGCR+SWCR+SGU+SWU))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = KrFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Rolf. The issue is with sharing the code is that it already flourished over a number of modules and sharing all of them will result in several metres of scrolling.